# windows 10 phone gets write protected while using in lumia 520

Tags: windows-10-mobile, insider-preview, lumia-520, flash-memory

My Windows 10 Mobile powered Lumia 520 starts restarting whenever I click on something. I tried to downgrade to Windows Phone 8.1 using the Windows recovery tool. Also tried to flash using thor showing as write protected. What do i need to do to make the phone work again, at least using Windows Phone 8.1.